# Error parsing NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript

Tags: ios, json, rest

Hello so i am trying to parse a json but every time i try i fail. i already tried this method that i have used lately and worked in all my other projects except this one. the json is valid.

```
 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=2&y=3&z=1"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"link-to-php.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
    NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *getJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                        JSONObjectWithData:requestHandler
                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                        error:&error];

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSArray *json = getJsonData[@"data"];



        for ( NSDictionary *jsn in json )
        {


            NSLog(@"dea %@",jsn[@"content"]);
        }





    }
```

And my JSON code is this

```
{"status":1,"error_message":null,"data":{"name":"Test","img":"","content":"Continut de test"}}
```

The error i get is

```
[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e7b7c0
2015-08-03 14:58:50.706 InfoCons[4418:1720073] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e7b7c0'
```

Comment: exactly at which line you're getting error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json formate return dictionary in dictionary formate data not array formate return in "data" key.

Try this code get data from json:

```
 if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",getJsonData[@"data"][@"content"]); // print value of dictionary
    }
```